# Escaping :: in a macro

Tags: c++

I've got a header with a macro to define new exception-subclasses:

```
#pragma once
#include <exception>
#include <string>

#define exc_subclass(base, deriv, default_what) \
struct deriv : public base \
{ \
    deriv( char const *what = default_what ) noexcept : \
        m_what( what ) \
    { \
    } \
    deriv( exception_ptr nextException, char const *what = default_what ) noexcept : \
        m_nextException( nextException ), \
        m_what( what ) \
    { \
    } \
    deriv( deriv const &other ) noexcept : \
        base( other ), \
        m_what( other.what() ) \
    { \
    } \
    virtual char const *what() const noexcept override \
    { \
        return m_what.c_str(); \
    } \
    std::exception_ptr next_exception() const noexcept \
    { \
        return m_nextException; \
    } \
private: \
    std::string        m_what; \
    std::exception_ptr m_nextException; \
};
```

But this doesn't accept ...

```
exc_subclass(std::exception, deriv, "my default what")
```

... because of the :: in it. Is there any escape for :: ?

Comment: I'm not sure what problem :: is giving you but it [appears to expand fine](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/PKvhGh).

Comment: Not with current MSVC 2019, @chris.

Comment: In that case, please add the compiler, and version that you're using, to the question. You might also want to add the appropriate compiler tag.

Comment: "doesn't accept" -> post the error message! What are we supposed to do without the error message?

Comment: You shouldn't implement the copy constructor. [Follow the rule of zero](http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Rc-zero)

Comment: A default copy-constructor woudn't initialize m_what with the result of a virtual call to other::what() @JHBonarius

Comment: ?? what are you talking about? https://godbolt.org/z/osadnY

Comment: And even more: as I've defined other constructors the default copy constructor isn't available.

Comment: My godbolt example seems to show otherwise...

Comment: Sorry, missed the last line: better godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/hTP8M8

Comment: Is the question about how to make the macro expand to the correct text or how to make that resulting text compile? Those are two entirely different questions and it sounds like they're being conflated. If it's the former, what exactly is Visual Studio expanding that macro invocation to compared to what you expect that makes you think the `::` is the probelm? My link demonstrates preprocessor output in another compiler, but that output still fails to compile. If it's the latter, I'd recommend getting rid of the macro from the question entirely because it's irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

After changing the line

```
deriv( exception_ptr nextException, char const *what = default_what ) noexcept : \
```

to

```
deriv( std::exception_ptr nextException, char const *what = default_what ) noexcept : \
```

The macro worked for me in Visual Studio. Might that be your issue?